# como ajusto mi html en IE si en chrome se ve bien

Tags: html, css, html5, html-tabla, css-grid-layout

no logro que los botones se ajusten exacto debajo de la ultima tabla y en IE cambian se desajustan

[image: los btn se ven distintos en IE]

Comment: versión de IE? HTML y CSS de la tabla y botones?

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el recorrido [CLICK AQUI](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera ademas de incluir el código del problema. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo en IE es poco probable de hacer por que el diseño que te es funcional en todos los navegadores populares (Google Chrome, Firefox, Vivaldi, Safari...) estos diseños se rompen en IE debido a que Microsoft quiso crear sus propios estándares que tiempo después recomendaron a todos sus usuarios dejar de usar ese navegador y te lo digo por experiencia propia que trabajar con ejemplos de IE es poco recomendable pero si quieres prueba aplicándole la propiedad en CSS de box-sizing:border-box; al elemento que quieres que se superponga o utiliza z-index:1000; si te funciona dime.

Puedes visitar los siguientes enlaces para comprobar:
http://www.bbc.com/mundo/noticias/2011/03/110305_1447_tecnologia_internet_explorer_ie6_microsoft_dc
http://www.falconmasters.com/css/propiedad-z-index/
http://www.falconmasters.com/css/como-cambiar-modelo-de-caja-navegadores-box-sizing-css/

Comment: Hola, la respuesta es buena, ¿podrías agregar referencias o ejemplos a tu respuesta? (Como esta podría ser considerada de baja calidad)

Comment: http://www.bbc.com/mundo/noticias/2011/03/110305_1447_tecnologia_internet_explorer_ie6_microsoft_dc                                                            http://www.falconmasters.com/css/propiedad-z-index/                             http://www.falconmasters.com/css/como-cambiar-modelo-de-caja-navegadores-box-sizing-css/

Comment: No la comentes, edita tu respuesta agregando esa información

Comment: Disculpa es que como tengo poco tiempo usando Stack Overflow y me gusta mucho esta pagina me ayuda cuando necesito información que no se

Comment: Te recomiendo ver [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), es importante dar respuestas calidad si se quiere ganar puntos y ayudar a la comunidad.